R CMD check claims, "no visible binding for global variable" for a defined dataset
I'm getting "undefined exports: countrySynonyms" from R CMD build acledr;  R CMD check acledr_0.0-1.tar.gz from the small R package at:
https://github.com/sbgraves237/acledr
I got this with Roxygen2, which I deleted.
countrySynonyms is a local copy of rworldmap::countrySynonyms, which R CMD check could not find for reasons I do not understand.
I DELETED NAMESPACE, after which a function no longer threw an error, because it was finally able to find countrySynonyms, though it still gave a NOTE saying, "no visible binding for global variable ‘countrySynonyms’".
A similar problem was solved by replacing "<<-" with "<-"; I could not find any use of "<<-" in this package. Another similar problem seems to have been solved by running "update.packages()"; I tried that without success. A third similar problem was reportedly solved by deleting a comment hash tag followed by an apostrophe, e.g., "#'Battlestar Galactica'", which Roxygen2 interpreted by replacing a desired export with two extraneous exports. I could not find #' anyplace in my code after I removed removed everywhere I had a hashtag followed by an apostrophe. Yet another similar problem was traced to problems with .Rbuildignore. I stripped .Rbuildignore down to one line, which fixed some problems but still left this one.
Suggestions?
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,
Spencer Graves

maybe it's getting confused between acledr's version of countrySynonyms and rworldmap's version of countrySynonyms?  Does it still happen if you change the name slightly?

you have still have a reference in your man pages

@wibeasley: No: I created the local copy of countrySynonyms BECAUSE I was having a similar problem with rworldmap::countrySynonyms. Now R can find it, and the remaining problem is now only a "NOTE", which CRAN will accept if I decide to submit it to CRAN. Thanks for the suggestion.
